# how to write separate error method while calling calling webservice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am calling webservice in factory method .I am getting call back in same method .Mean If I got success it call same method . when it come error it call same method .I need to write separated method as we do in ajax .success and error .

I do like this

```
app.factory('mainInfo', function($http) {



    return {
        getFooOldSchool: function(callback) {
            $http.get('http://198.126.129.143:8180/FG/js/rest/test').success(callback).error(callback);
        }
    }
});

    function cnt($scope,$http,mainInfo){
        $scope.hideorshow=false;
        $scope.loading=true;
        mainInfo.getFooOldSchool(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('==')
            $scope.d=data;
            $scope.hideorshow=true;
            $scope.loading=false;
            //alert(data);
        }) ;
    })
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getFooOldSchool: function(callback) {`

to

```
getFooOldSchool: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
$http.get(...).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
```

and pass in two handlers:

```
   mainInfo.getFooOldSchool(function(data){
   ...success callback
    }, 
    function(data){ ...error callback  });
```